# What happens to unsaved data after app goes to the background in iOS

Tags: ios

For how long does the data entered in a certain app lasts after the app is closed and in the background?

In other words, if I have an app which allows the user to enter items into a tableview but the app does NOT have a way to persist the data, such as coredata, UserDefaults, Realm etc. and the user closes the app after he/she entered a few items into the table, for how long does that data will be available? When does iOS will purge that data?

Can someone explain what happens to unsaved data once the app has been closed?

Comment: "Closed" is a vague term. If you do not persist the data, it exists in memory only and thu is wiped in states your app does not remain in memory. See https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/TheAppLifeCycle/TheAppLifeCycle.html.

Comment: If your app is in background then your data will be there when user opens it again. but user removes your app from background then data will erased from the app.

Comment: @shallowThought - After reading the documentation you provided, if I understand it correctly there is no specific time or cycle where the data is lost since the OS can terminate the app at any time for many reasons so, the data could sit there for days months if the OS doesn't have a need for terminating it or only for a few minutes if more intense process are preformed by other apps , is that correct?

Comment: @KAR - That's what I thought but I have seen instances where the app has not been removed and the data is lost in the background.

Comment: @fs_tigre As long as you are not in foreground, correct. Ceckout the `AppDelegate` calls (in the linked documentation) to handle state changes.

Answer (score 1):

you can figure out when it happens, this delegate function in AppDelegate will get called when your app is getting terminated, every unstored data will be gone

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
}
```

Comment: Quick question: Is the `applicationWillTerminate` method a common place to add code that persists data that hasn't been saved by the user or  the `applicationDidEnterBackground` or both?

Comment: This method is not always called. Do not rely on it to save data. Save data when the app enters the background.

Comment: @rmaddy - Thank you for the clarification.  Quick question - Is the `applicationWillTerminate` method called when the app unexpectedly quits/crashes?

Comment: @fs_tigre - no, if the app chrashes everything is "canceled"

Comment: @fs_tigre No it is not called on a crash.

Comment: @rmaddy - @ Stoneburner - If I understand this correctly there is no good way to prevent data loss when a crash occurs, correct?

Comment: @fs_tigre  correct, there is nothing you can do in the event of a crash, you are better off saving the data as soon as you have them

Comment: @Stoneburner - Thanks a lot for your help.